# python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'

Tags: python, python-2.7

What im trying to do is watch a folder with pyinotify and any mp3's that are dropped into that folder eyed3 picks up the ID3 tags (and later adds to a database). This works perfectly the first time a file is dropped in the folder but if I then add a second file it will crash with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 25, in <module>
    notifier.loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 1424, in loop
    self.process_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 1321, in process_events
    self._default_proc_fun(revent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 960, in __call__
    return _ProcessEvent.__call__(self, event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 680, in __call__
    return meth(event)
  File "./test.py", line 16, in process_IN_CREATE
    print track.tag.artist
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

My code so far:

```
import pyinotify
import eyed3

# The watch manager stores the watches and provides operations on watches
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

mask = pyinotify.IN_CREATE  # watched events

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        name = event.pathname
        track = eyed3.load(name)
        print track.tag.artist
        print track.tag.title
        print track.tag.album
        print track.info.bit_rate[1]

handler = EventHandler()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
wdd = wm.add_watch('/home/mark/Desktop/test', mask, rec=True)
notifier.loop()
```

Note: Its not a case of the tag being empty either tracks work on the first go but never the second

Comment: Looks like `eyed3.load(name)` returned None.

Comment: I don't know how either of those packages you're using work, but `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'` means that `track` is `None` when you call it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo you're absolutely right I just added some error checking to see if eyed3 was returning anything and sometimes it doesn't return anything but I can then drop the same song in the folder again and it works fine.... really strange behaviour

Comment: `eyed3.load(name)` returns None, if the MIME type is not recognised. It also puts debug messages with the `logging` module.

Comment: @tynn thank you for your input but as mentioned in my post the mp3 works the first time its only when i drag a second file into the folder the error happens no matter if that file worked the first time it will never work if its the second